# Laravel 7 Vue Dropzone - Unable to display images from storage. Filename not getting uploaded to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-7, dropzone

I have successfully loaded the supplied image to the storage in the public folder within the images folder via Dropzone js. I am unclear on how to upload the reference to my phpmyadmin SQL database. If I hard code it into the db, I can see it displayed on the page. However, with the form I am using, I am calling the component within my update tasks form. I am not sure if this is why it is not working but in any case, I will post the code in the hopes someone can orient me in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

ImageController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $imageName = time() . '.' . $request->file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->file->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
        return response()->json(['success' => 'You have successfully uploaded the file(s).']);
}
```

web.php

```
Route::post('store-multiple-image', 'ImageController@store');
```

app.js

```
Vue.component(
    "multiple-image-component",
    require("./components/MultipleImageUploadComponent.vue").default
);
```

TaskController.php (store method only for brevity)

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        // $this->validate($request, [
        //     'name' => 'required|string|max:191',
        //     'email' => 'required|string|email|max:191|unique:users',
        //     'password' => 'required|string|min:6'
        // ]);

        return Task::create([
            'task_name' => $request['task_name'],
            'task_priority' => $request['task_priority'],
            'task_assigned_to' => $request['task_assigned_to'],
            'task_assigned_by' => $request['task_assigned_by'],
            'task_description' => $request['task_description'],
            'task_to_be_completed_date' => $request['task_to_be_completed_date'],
            'task_status' => $request['task_status'],
            'task_notes' => $request['task_notes'],
            'task_finished' => $request['task_finished'],
            'image' => $request['image'],

        ]);
    }
```

Tasks.vue (I have included everything here just in case I am causing a conflict somewhere)

```
<template>
  <div class="custom-container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card w-100">
          <div class="card-header text-white" style="background-color: #605ca8;">
            <h3 class="card-title">Tasks</h3>

            <div class="card-tools">
              <button class="btn btn-success" @click="newModal">
                <i class="fas fa-tasks"></i> Add New Task
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.card-header -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id">
      <div class="my-3 p-3 bg-white rounded box-shadow">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5>Task</h5>
            <hr />
            <p>{{ task.task_name }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5>Priority</h5>
            <hr />
            <p>{{ task.task_priority }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5>Assigned To</h5>
            <hr />
            <p>{{ task.task_assigned_to }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5>Assigned By</h5>
            <hr />
            <p>{{ task.task_assigned_by }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5>Date Assigned</h5>
            <hr />
            <p>{{ task.created_at }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5>Due</h5>
            <hr />
            <p>{{ task.task_to_be_completed_date }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5>Task Description</h5>
            <hr />
            <p>{{ task.task_description }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5>Finished</h5>
            <hr />
            <p>{{ task.task_finished }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5>Status</h5>
            <hr />
            <p>{{ task.task_status }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5>Images</h5>
            <hr />
            <img style="max-width: 150px;" :src="'/images/' + task.image" alt />
            <br />
            <img style="max-width: 150px;" src="/img/molding.jpg" alt />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5>Notes</h5>
            <hr />
            <p>{{ task.task_notes }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5>Action</h5>
            <hr />
            <a href="#" class="badge badge-primary p-2 mb-3" @click="editModal(task)">
              <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
            </a>
            <a @click="deleteTask(task.id)" href="#" class="badge badge-danger p-2">
              <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <form @submit.prevent="editmode ? updateTask() : createTask()">
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div
        class="modal fade"
        id="addNew"
        tabindex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="addNewLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" v-show="!editmode" id="addNewLabel">Add New Task</h5>
              <h5 class="modal-title" v-show="editmode" id="addNewLabel">Update Task Information</h5>

              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  id="task_name"
                  type="text"
                  v-model="form.task_name"
                  name="task_name"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Task Name"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'task_name'
                                        )
                                    }"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="task_name"></has-error>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select
                  id="task_priority"
                  type="text"
                  v-model="form.task_priority"
                  name="task_priority"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'task_priority'
                                        )
                                    }"
                >
                  <option value>Select a Priority Level</option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                  <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
                <has-error :form="form" field="task_priority"></has-error>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea
                  id="task_description"
                  type="text"
                  v-model="form.task_description"
                  name="task_description"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Task Description"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'task_description'
                                        )
                                    }"
                ></textarea>
                <has-error :form="form" field="task_description"></has-error>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  id="task_assigned_by"
                  type="text"
                  v-model="form.task_assigned_by"
                  name="task_assigned_by"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Assigned By"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'task_assigned_by'
                                        )
                                    }"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="task_assigned_by"></has-error>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  id="task_assigned_to"
                  type="text"
                  v-model="form.task_assigned_to"
                  name="task_assigned_to"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Assigned To"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'task_assigned_to'
                                        )
                                    }"
                  value="form.user.id"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="task_assigned_to"></has-error>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="task_to_be_completed_date">Due:</label>
                <input
                  id="task_to_be_completed_date"
                  type="date"
                  v-model="form.task_to_be_completed_date"
                  name="task_to_be_completed_date"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Due: "
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'task_to_be_completed_date'
                                        )
                                    }"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="task_to_be_completed_date"></has-error>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select
                  id="task_status"
                  type="text"
                  v-model="form.task_status"
                  name="task_status"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'task_status'
                                        )
                                    }"
                >
                  <option value>Select Task Status</option>
                  <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                  <option value="Finished">Finished</option>
                  <option value="Incomplete">Incomplete</option>
                </select>
                <has-error :form="form" field="task_status"></has-error>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <select
                  id="task_finished"
                  type="text"
                  v-model="form.task_finished"
                  name="task_finished"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'task_finished'
                                        )
                                    }"
                >
                  <option value>Select finished status</option>
                  <option value="Finished">Finished</option>
                  <option value="Unfinished">Unfinished</option>
                </select>
                <has-error :form="form" field="task_status"></has-error>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="task_notes">Notes:</label>
                <textarea
                  id="task_notes"
                  type="text"
                  v-model="form.task_notes"
                  name="task_notes"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Notes: "
                  :class="{
                                        'is-invalid': form.errors.has(
                                            'task_notes'
                                        )
                                    }"
                ></textarea>
                <has-error :form="form" field="task_notes"></has-error>
              </div>
              <multiple-image-component></multiple-image-component>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button v-show="editmode" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
              <button v-show="!editmode" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create New Task</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      editmode: true,
      tasks: {},
      attachments: [],
      // formImage: new FormData(),
      form: new Form({
        id: "",
        task_name: "",
        task_description: "",
        task_assigned_by: "",
        task_assigned_to: "",
        task_to_be_completed_date: "",
        task_priority: "",
        task_notes: "",
        task_status: "",
        task_finished: "",
        task_image: "",
      }),
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateTask() {
      this.$Progress.start();
      this.form
        .put("api/task/" + this.form.id)
        .then(() => {
          // successfull
          $("#addNew").modal("hide");
          Swal.fire("Updated", "Task information updated.", "success");
          this.$Progress.finish();
          Fire_event.$emit("AfterCreate");
        })
        .catch(() => {
          // Unsuccessfull
          this.$Progress.fail();
        });
    },
    editModal(task) {
      this.editmode = true;
      this.form.reset();
      $("#addNew").modal("show");
      this.form.fill(task);
    },
    newModal() {
      this.editmode = false;
      this.form.reset();
      $("#addNew").modal("show");
    },
    deleteTask(id) {
      Swal.fire({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        icon: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
        cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
      }).then((result) => {
        // Send request to the server
        if (result.value) {
          this.form
            .delete("api/task/" + id)
            .then(() => {
              Swal.fire("Deleted!", "Task has been deleted.", "success");

              Fire_event.$emit("AfterCreate");
            })
            .catch(() => {
              Swal.fire("Failed", "Something went wrong.", "warning");
            });
        }
      });
    },
    loadTasks() {
      axios.get("api/task").then(({ data }) => (this.tasks = data.data));
    },
    createTask() {
      this.$Progress.start();
      this.form
        .post("api/task")
        .then(() => {
          Fire_event.$emit("AfterCreate");
          $("#addNew").modal("hide");
          toast.fire({
            icon: "success",
            title: "Task Created successfully",
          });
          this.$Progress.finish();
          this.target.reset();
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.$Progress.fail();
          //   toast.fire({
          //     icon: "error",
          //     title: "The Task was not created.",
          //   });
        });
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.loadTasks();
    // setInterval(() => this.loadUsers(), 3000);
    Fire_event.$on("AfterCreate", () => {
      this.loadTasks();
    });
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("Component mounted.");
  },
};
</script>
```

Task.php (Model)

```
protected $fillable = [
        'task_name', 'task_priority', 'task_assigned_to', 'task_assigned_by', 'task_description', 'task_to_be_completed_date', 'task_status',
        'task_notes', 'task_finished', 'image'
    ];
```

And finally, the MultipleImageUploadComponent.vue from Dropzone

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-start">
            <div class="">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Task Image</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <vue-dropzone
                            ref="myVueDropzone"
                            id="dropzone"
                            :options="dropzoneOptions"
                        ></vue-dropzone>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import vue2Dropzone from "vue2-dropzone";
import "vue2-dropzone/dist/vue2Dropzone.min.css";

export default {
    components: {
        vueDropzone: vue2Dropzone
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            dropzoneOptions: {
                url: "/store-multiple-image",
                headers: {
                    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document.head.querySelector(
                        "[name=csrf-token]"
                    ).content
                }
            }
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log("Component mounted.");
    }
};
</script>
```

I am new to combining vue and laravel so if you can help me out, I would sure appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Now, Dropzone uses an Ajax request and so does the method I was trying to use to upload the rest of my form. This creates a conflict and out of the box, Dropzone will not allow this functionality.

At least now without a log of configuring. In my case, Dropzone is not a viable option and I have to look for a different option to upload multiple images within my form.

Comment: "Please consider this question closed"—you could just... _close your question_. I'm not sure that this counts as an answer.